# How to use if condition inside a loop?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I want to solve a problem given by our teacher. The problem is: make a Python program that verifies if a number is a *perfect square*. If it's a perfect square it, shows a message and if not it shows another message.

This is my attempt:

```py
n = int(input('choose a number'))
for i in range(1,n):
    if n//i==i:
        d=i
print(n,'is a perfect square and its root is,',d)
```

During my attempt, I couldn't add the `else` condition where the number is not a perfect square.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Note that `5//2 == 2` but `5` is not a perfect square!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your range method and without importing math, you could have done this:

```
n = int(input('choose a number: '))
for i in range(1,n+1):
    if i**2 == n:   ## square the i and see if it equals n
        print(n,'is a perfect square and its root is:',i)
        break       ## stop here 
       
    else:
      if i == n:    ## when all the i's have been tried, give up
        print(n,'is not a perfect square')
```

Answer (score 0):

you gave this a good go. Has your teacher taught you about importing **modules** yet? Basically, a module is like a Python file, and you can take functions from that file and use them in your file. One **module is 'math'** and holds a **function called 'sqrt'** that calculates the square root of a given number. If this square root is a whole number (has no remainder) the given number is square -- is not, it's not square. See the program I wrote below:

```
import math

num = int(input("Number = "))
square_root = math.sqrt(num)
if square_root % 1 == 0:
    print(f"It's square. {int(square_root)} squared gives {num}")
else:
    print("It's not square")
```

Comment: thank you for ur answer, but please can u clarify why squar_root%1=0?  i think even a rational number%1=0 or am i wrong?

Comment: If you're using the `math` module, you might as well use `math.isqrt` instead of `math.sqrt`. That way it'll work for arbitrarily large integers, without the problems introduced by floating-point. (E.g., `2**52 + 2**27` is not a perfect square, but this method would report it as one.)